# Error de Variable en parseo

Tags: javascript, geojson

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al declarar listbooks mediante:

```
let listBooks = JSON.parse(`<?php echo $arrNoticias2?>`);
```

realicé un `var_dump` a **$arrNoticias2**, mostrando la data.

Lo que no logro solucionar por que me sale ese error de que no está declarado **listBooks**.

Comment: Pon el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, ¿dónde se hace la llamada a _openModal_? ¿Dónde está ubicado el script? El orden es importante. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta, y pon un título descriptivo a la misma.

Comment: Quizás lo que no está definido es `[index]`... Planteate hacer un `console.log(listBooks)` antes y ver que sale. Pon el código en modo texto para que lo podamos copiar y practicar con el para ayudarte. Una imagen de código no ayuda mucho y no son bien aceptadas en la comunidad. Y por favor, aunque te parezca obvio, pega exactamente la linea del error que se ha producido en la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: Por si acaso, veo que eso esta dentro de un array, así que quizas deberias probar con `listBooks[0].['index']`.

Comment: debes encoder antes del echo ejemplo: `<?php echo json_encode($arrNoticias2, true);?>` saludos